# R sum by group if date within date range

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, sumifs, non-equi-join

Suppose I have two dataframes.

The first one includes "Date" at which a "Name" issues a "Rec" for an "ID" and the "Stop.Date" at which "Rec" becomes invalid.

**df (only a part)**

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(13236, 13363, 14074, 13199, 
14554), class = "Date"), ID = c("AU0000XINAA9", "AU0000XINAA9", 
"AU0000XINAC5", "AU0000XINAI2", "AU0000XINAJ0"), Name = c("N+1 BREWIN", 
"N+1 BREWIN", "ARBUTHNOT SECURITIES LTD.", "INVESTEC BANK (UK) PLC", 
"AWRAQ INVESTMENTS"), Rec = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1), Stop.Date = structure(c(13363, 
13509, 14937, 13230, 16702), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Date", 
"ID", "Name", "Rec", "Stop.Date"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

The Second dataframe only contains a time series: Let's say in this case from 2006-03-29 until end of 2006.

**df2**

```
      Date1
  1: 2006-02-20
  2: 2006-02-21
  3: 2006-02-22
  4: 2006-02-23
  5: 2006-02-24
 ---           
311: 2006-12-27
312: 2006-12-28
313: 2006-12-29
314: 2006-12-30
315: 2006-12-31
```

Now I want my code to sum all "Rec" gouped by ID and Name if the "Date1" variable in df2 falls within the time range (Date until Stop.Date)

I found this post [R - If date falls within range, then sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049441/r-if-date-falls-within-range-then-sum) and it seems very close to my problem but the solution does not consider any groups.

I want to come up with a data.frame in which for each date in **df2** the sum  of "REC" for each single "ID" is shown.

**Expected output e.g.**

```
        Date1         ID          SumRec 

    1 2006-02-20 AU0000XINAI2        2
    2 2006-02-21 AU0000XINAI2        2
...
    4 2006-03-29 AU0000XINAA9        1
    5 2006-03-30 AU0000XINAA9        1
    6 2006-08-03 AU0000XINAA9        2  # since Date1 2006-08-03 is at the end 
                                          of range in df (row#1)-> it falls 
                                          within range in df (row#2) 
...
```

Please keep in mind this is only a small part of the data. Usually there exists many more Recs for each "ID" from different "Names". (then sum function makes sense)

Many thanks for your help in advance.

**UPDATED VERSION**

new dataframes:

**df**

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(9905, 10381, 10381, 10954, 
10584, 10632, 10778, 10520, 10631, 10905), class = "Date"), ID = c("BMG4593F1389", 
"BMG4593F1389", "BMG4593F1389", "BMG4593F1389", "BMG4593F1389", 
"BMG4593F1389", "BMG4593F1389", "BMG526551004", "BMG526551004", 
"BMG526551004"), Name = c("ING FM", "Permission Denied 128064", 
"Permission Denied 2880", "Permission Denied 2880", "Permission Denied 32", 
"Permission Denied 888", "Permission Denied 888", "Permission Denied 2880", 
"Permission Denied 2880", "Permission Denied 2880"), Rec = c(2, 
3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3), Stop.Date = structure(c(12095, 11232, 
10954, 11180, 11345, 10764, 11667, 10631, 10905, 11087), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Date", 
"ID", "Name", "Rec", "Stop.Date"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

**df2**

```
structure(list(Date1 = structure(c(10954, 10955, 10956, 10957, 
10958, 10959), class = "Date")), .Names = "Date1", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

If I now execute the following code:

```
> df=df[,interval := interval(df$Date, df$Stop.Date)]
> 
> df1 <- do.call(rbind, lapply(df2$Date1, function(x){   index <- x
> %within% df$interval;   list(ID = ifelse(any(index), df$ID[index],
> NA), Rec = ifelse(any(index), df$Rec[index], NA), 
>        Name = ifelse(any(index), df$Name[index], NA),interval = ifelse(any(index),df$interval[index],NA))})) 
> 
> df3 <- cbind(df2, df1)
```

I come up with the following result:

```
     Date1        ID        Rec  Name interval
1: 1999-12-29 BMG4593F1389   2 ING FM 189216000
2: 1999-12-30 BMG4593F1389   2 ING FM 189216000
3: 1999-12-31 BMG4593F1389   2 ING FM 189216000
4: 2000-01-01 BMG4593F1389   2 ING FM 189216000
5: 2000-01-02 BMG4593F1389   2 ING FM 189216000
6: 2000-01-03 BMG4593F1389   2 ING FM 189216000
```

But since e.g the df2$Date1 ("1999-12-29") for the df$ID "BMG4593F1389" falls within the date range of 6 more entries in df (for different df$Names) FOR THIS particular df$date1 it should be:

**Expected result for  Date 1999-12-29** (df3$interval variable neglected here for simplicity)

```
         Date1        ID        Rec         Name 
    1: 1999-12-29 BMG4593F1389   2   ING FM 
    2: 1999-12-29 BMG4593F1389   3   Permission Denied 128064 
    3: 1999-12-29 BMG4593F1389   2   Permission Denied 2880
    4: 1999-12-29 BMG4593F1389   3   Permission Denied 32
    5: 1999-12-29 BMG4593F1389   3   Permission Denied 888

    6: 1999-12-29 BMG5265510042  3   Permission Denied 2880

    7: 1999-12-30 BMG4593F1389   2   ING FM
... etc
```

So at the end I need the Dates in df$Date1 replicated if more than one name issues a Rec for a specific df$ID which falls within the respective date range.

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: What is your expected output? Please show at least several lines preferably with explanation

Comment: Do you want to get the sum of `Rec` or simply the `Rec` for each date in `df2$Date1`?

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense. Your sample data start on `2006-03-29`

Comment: yes that's true. Sorry for the confusion, please assume sample data df2 starts at the earliest date of df (2006-02-20)

Comment: I have a follow up question and therefor updated my question above. Would be great if you could take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand *the updated version* of the question correctly, this can be solved using a *non-equi join* and subsequent aggregation:

```
library(data.table)
# non-equi join
df[df2, on = .(Date <= Date1, Stop.Date > Date1), allow = TRUE][
  # aggregation
  , .(sumRec = sum(Rec)), by = .(Date, ID, Name)]
```

> ```
>           Date           ID                     Name sumRec
>  1: 1999-12-29 BMG4593F1389                   ING FM      2
>  2: 1999-12-29 BMG4593F1389 Permission Denied 128064      3
>  3: 1999-12-29 BMG4593F1389   Permission Denied 2880      2
>  4: 1999-12-29 BMG4593F1389     Permission Denied 32      3
>  5: 1999-12-29 BMG4593F1389    Permission Denied 888      3
>  6: 1999-12-29 BMG526551004   Permission Denied 2880      3
>  7: 1999-12-30 BMG4593F1389                   ING FM      2
>  8: 1999-12-30 BMG4593F1389 Permission Denied 128064      3
>  9: 1999-12-30 BMG4593F1389   Permission Denied 2880      2
> 10: 1999-12-30 BMG4593F1389     Permission Denied 32      3
> 11: 1999-12-30 BMG4593F1389    Permission Denied 888      3
> 12: 1999-12-30 BMG526551004   Permission Denied 2880      3
> 13: 1999-12-31 BMG4593F1389                   ING FM      2
> 14: 1999-12-31 BMG4593F1389 Permission Denied 128064      3
> 15: 1999-12-31 BMG4593F1389   Permission Denied 2880      2
> 16: 1999-12-31 BMG4593F1389     Permission Denied 32      3
> 17: 1999-12-31 BMG4593F1389    Permission Denied 888      3
> 18: 1999-12-31 BMG526551004   Permission Denied 2880      3
> 19: 2000-01-01 BMG4593F1389                   ING FM      2
> 20: 2000-01-01 BMG4593F1389 Permission Denied 128064      3
> 21: 2000-01-01 BMG4593F1389   Permission Denied 2880      2
> 22: 2000-01-01 BMG4593F1389     Permission Denied 32      3
> 23: 2000-01-01 BMG4593F1389    Permission Denied 888      3
> 24: 2000-01-01 BMG526551004   Permission Denied 2880      3
> 25: 2000-01-02 BMG4593F1389                   ING FM      2
> 26: 2000-01-02 BMG4593F1389 Permission Denied 128064      3
> 27: 2000-01-02 BMG4593F1389   Permission Denied 2880      2
> 28: 2000-01-02 BMG4593F1389     Permission Denied 32      3
> 29: 2000-01-02 BMG4593F1389    Permission Denied 888      3
> 30: 2000-01-02 BMG526551004   Permission Denied 2880      3
> 31: 2000-01-03 BMG4593F1389                   ING FM      2
> 32: 2000-01-03 BMG4593F1389 Permission Denied 128064      3
> 33: 2000-01-03 BMG4593F1389   Permission Denied 2880      2
> 34: 2000-01-03 BMG4593F1389     Permission Denied 32      3
> 35: 2000-01-03 BMG4593F1389    Permission Denied 888      3
> 36: 2000-01-03 BMG526551004   Permission Denied 2880      3
>           Date           ID                     Name sumRec
> ```

Please, note that I experienced a strange error message when using `df` as provided in `structure(...)` directly. The error message went away after calling

```
df <- as.data.table(df)
```

#### Explanation

I was [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662243/r-sum-by-group-if-date-within-date-range/49673599?noredirect=1#comment86366221_49673599) to explain how the *non-equi join* works. *Non-equi joins* are an extension of the `data.table` joins. `data.table` is a package which enhances base R's `data.frame`.

Here, we right join `df2` with `df`, i.e., we want to see all rows of `df2` with matches in `df` in the result but only those where `Date1` (from `df2`) lies between `Date` and `Stop.Date` (from `df`), `Date <= Date1 < Stop.Date` to be exact. As there are many possible matches, we need to use `allow.cartesian = TRUE`.

There is a [video of Arun's talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/useR-international-R-User-conference/useR2016/Efficient-in-memory-non-equi-joins-using-datatable) at the useR! 2016 international R User conference introducing *Efficient in-memory non-equi joins using data.table*.

Comment: May I ask what does `allow = TRUE` do? This is the first time I've seen that option I think. Thanks!

Comment: Seems to work perfectly! I just edited the sum function to simply "rec" because I only want the Rec value in this dataframe. many thanks for the simple solution. Since I am quite new to R, would you mind to explain how non-equi join works in this case?

Comment: @Tung By default, `allow.cartesian` is `FALSE` to prevent joins that would result in more than `nrow(x) + nrow(i)` rows which are  caused by duplicate values in `i`’s join columns. Here, we need all possible combinations which will be aggregated in the second step.

Comment: @JB_G I have added an additional explanation on *non-equi joins*.