# R summaries when dates in main df fall within ranges from small df

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, sumifs, non-equi-join

Similar to do.call/lapply approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049441/r-if-date-falls-within-range-then-sum), and data.table approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662243/r-sum-by-group-if-date-within-date-range), but both have the setup of:

- MainDF with data and startdate/enddate ranges
- SubDF with a vector of single dates

Where the users are looking for summaries of all the MainDF ranges that overlap each SubDF date. I have

- MainDF with data and a vector of single dates
- SubDF with startdate/enddate ranges

And am looking to append summaries, to SubDF, for multiple rows of MainDF data which fall within each SubDF range. Example:

```
library(lubridate)
MainDF <- data.frame(Dates = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020-02-12"),
                                      by = "days",
                                      length.out = 10),
                     DataA = 1:10)
SubDF <- data.frame(DateFrom = as.Date(c("2020-02-13", "2020-02-16", "2020-02-19")),
                    DateTo = as.Date(c("2020-02-14", "2020-02-17", "2020-02-21")))
SubDF$interval <- interval(SubDF$DateFrom, SubDF$DateTo)
```

Trying the data.table approach from the second link I figure it should be something like:

```
MainDF[SubDF, on = .(Dates >= DateFrom, Dates <= DateTo), allow = TRUE][
, .(SummaryStat = max(DataA)), by = .(Dates)]
```

But it errors with unused arguments for `on`. On my actual data I got a result by using (the equivalent of) `max(MainDF$DataA)`, but it was 3 repeats of the second value (In my actual data the final row won't run as it doesn't have a value for DateTo). I suspect using `MainDF$` means I've subverting the grouping.

I suspect I'm close but I'm really struggling to get my head around the `data.table` mindset for complex use cases. The summary stats I'm looking to do are (for example data):

- `Mean` & `Max` of DataA
- `length(which(DataA > 3))`
- `difftime(last(Dates), first(Dates), units = "mins")`
- `Dates[which.max(DataA)]`

I added the `interval` line above as `data.table`'s `%between%` help suggests one might be able to use a `Dates %between% interval` format but it doesn't mention intervals/difftimes specifically in the text nor examples and my attempts are already failing elsewhere so I'm loathe to concentrate on improving my running while I can't walk!

I've focused on the data.table approach since it's used for a similar problem, but I've been wondering whether `dplyr`'s `group_by`/`group_by_if` could be used instead? `group_by_if`'s `.predicate` seems to be constrained to tests on the columns (e.g. are they factors) rather than relating to data in the columns' rows, but I could be wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: for *But it errors with unused arguments for on*, you need to convert your dataset to `data.table` first using `setDT(MainDF)` and `setDT(SubDF)`

Comment: As @chinsoon12 pointed out, your code works when you `setDT` both of your data.frames.

Comment: oh goodness... thanks both. I had `as.data.table` for one of them but evidently not both, and maybe not the right syntax. I'll give it a try tomorrow when my megaloop has finished! Cheers :)